# Stripe subscriptions - how to format cancel_at date

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

So I'm trying to create a monthly subscription that will cancel in 2020-10-10

I pass such an object:

```
     return stripe.subscriptions.create ({
       customer: customer.id,
       items: [{plan: plan.id}],
       expand: ["latest_invoice.payment_intent"],
       cancel_at: new Date('2020-10-10').getTime()
     }
```

But on the Stripe dashboard, the subscription is as follows:

[image]

And I don't understand how I need to send the subscription cancellation date to cancel the subscription on the date I want
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Try using Date(2020,10,10). I think when you use strings for JS dates, they have to be passed in a specific format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `JS` `Date.getTime()` method returns the time in milliseconds. The stripe api is expecting the time in seconds.

The simple conversion for milliseconds to seconds is:

```
Time in milliseconds / 1000 = Time in seconds
```

Your code should be:

```js
const cancelAt = (new Date('2020-10-10').getTime()) / 1000;

return stripe.subscriptions.create ({
  customer: customer.id,
  items: [{plan: plan.id}],
  expand: ["latest_invoice.payment_intent"],
  cancel_at: cancelAt
}
```